# Is that possible to filter and display the lookup values?

Tags: list, lookup-column, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a filtered lookup field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-make-a-filtered-lookup-field)

I am using project list lookup field in task list, so my project have # of items, but i need to restrict some of the project like if the status is "Closed" that should not refelect in task list lookup field column. is there any option to do this?

Do we have option to use the CAML query to achive this?