# Adding SPFieldLookup to specific content types in Custom List

Tags: content-type, spfield

I have a custom list that contains a number of custom content types.  When a web is provisioned this custom list is provisioned.

In addition to custom list is an Asset Library which is will serve as the source of a lookup field is also provisioned.

I need to create a SPFieldLookup on my custom list which looks up items in the Asset Library but ONLY for one specific content type.  This is so when the user selects the specific content type the SPFieldLookup field appears on the form.  I don't, however, want this SPFieldLookup on any of the other content type forms.

I have no idea how to do this and I am hoping it can be done in a straight forward manner.

The Web UI gives an option to add a field to all content types when you add a field to a list but no option to specify one specifically.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Out of the Box way of filtering a Lookup column based on any field OR on Content Type.. However you can use following CodePlex Project:

2007: http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/
2010: http://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/

PS: Please have a look at [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-make-a-filtered-lookup-field)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom content type and add the SPFieldLookup field there.

Add the custom content type to your custom list.

Unless I am missing something