# Online - Filter the options of a lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, infopath, lookup-column

I'm using SharePoint Online.

In the "Contact" list have a calculated column with this formula:

```
IF([Active],[Last Name]&" "&[First Name],"")
```

This formula is working fine.

In another list I have a lookup field referred to this column. But when I try to add a new item with the InfoPath form, it shows all values (with empty values too) in the dropdown.

Has something changed since this post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/206144/20605 ? Or am I doing something wrong?