# How can I force one to one relationship in SharePoint lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, custom-list, custom-form, splistitem

I have one parent list and only one child can be associated with one parent item. For example, 
Employee -> company access card

Each employee can have one access card and new access card can only be created when certain conditions are met in the employee list

Comment: You have to add some (workflow) code, SharePoint is not a Relational Database

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman  can you please point me to any sample online, i am trying to search but my be my "search terms" are not correct.

Comment: I don't know any example which turns SharePoint into a Relational Database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you have Employee list(Parent list) and Access card list (Child list) with lookup column "Employee" from parent list.

To force one to one relationship, in child list lookup column, select the option "Enforce Unique Values". This will make sure that only one item added in child list per employee.

[image]

Comment: Thank you . This is what I was looking for. I assumed this unique was for something else

Comment: Can I apply more validations before child item is created? I mean like check if some Boolean field in parent is "true" or false?

Comment: For this you can create calculated column in Parent list. Then in formula check whether Boolean filed is True or False and if true populate employee value in this Calculated Column. Now refer this Calulated column in Lookup filed of child list.

Comment: Check Accepted answer at below link, this will help you http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-make-a-filtered-lookup-field